# questions about amcl and hector slam

Tags: ros, rviz, odometry, amcl, tf

My current urdf files have base_link and base_footprint as parents and child links , however i want to use amcl , i have another launch file for amcl which publishes the odom frame , but my urdf files is preventing the  odom frame from coming out in the tree , because it doesnt have a link.

1. Do i add an additional link to link my odom frame? If so how do i add the odom link
2. Is it better to use hector slam to do localisation? i currently alr have a map from gmapping. (because i dont have odom)

thankyou